# Kubernetes - segfault in libnftnl.so.11.3.0 on flannel CNI

Tags: kubernetes, flannel, cni

I have a self managed Kubernetes cluster consisting of one master node and 3 worker nodes. I use the Cluster Network Interface [flannel](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel#flannel) within the cluster.

On all my machines I can see the following kind of kernel messages:

```
Apr 12 04:22:24 worker-7 kernel: [278523.379954] iptables[6260]: segfault at 88 ip 00007f9e69fefe47 sp 00007ffee4dff356 error 4 in libnftnl.so.11.3.0[7f9e69feb000+16000]
Apr 12 04:22:24 worker-7 kernel: [278523.380094] Code: bf 88 00 00 00 48 8b 2f 48 39 df 74 13 4c 89 ee 41 ff d4 85 c0 78 0b 48 89 ef 48 8b 6d 00 eb e8 31 c0 5a 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d c3 <48> 8b 87 88 00 00 00 48 81 c7 78 00 00 00 48 39 f8 74 0b 85 f6 74
Apr 12 05:59:10 worker-7 kernel: [284329.182667] iptables[13978]: segfault at 88 ip 00007fb799fafe47 sp 00007fff22419b36 error 4 in libnftnl.so.11.3.0[7fb799fab000+16000]
Apr 12 05:59:10 worker-7 kernel: [284329.182774] Code: bf 88 00 00 00 48 8b 2f 48 39 df 74 13 4c 89 ee 41 ff d4 85 c0 78 0b 48 89 ef 48 8b 6d 00 eb e8 31 c0 5a 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d c3 <48> 8b 87 88 00 00 00 48 81 c7 98 00 00 00 48 39 f8 74 0b 85 f6 74
Apr 12 08:29:25 worker-7 kernel: [293343.999073] iptables[16041]: segfault at 88 ip 00007fa40c7f7e47 sp 00007ffe04ba9886 error 4 in libnftnl.so.11.3.0[7fa40c7f3000+16000]
Apr 12 08:29:25 worker-7 kernel: [293343.999165] Code: bf 88 00 00 00 48 8b 2f 48 39 df 74 13 4c 89 ee 41 ff d4 85 c0 78 0b 48 89 ef 48 8b 6d 00 eb e8 31 c0 5a 5b 5d 41 5c 41 5d c3 <48> 8b 87 88 00 00 00 48 81 c7 98 00 00 00 48 39 f8 74 0b 85 f6 74
```

I narrowed it down that the messages originated in the kube-flannel-ds pods. I have log messages like this one:

```
Failed to ensure iptables rules: Error checking rule existence: failed to check rule existence: running [/sbin/iptables -t filter -C FORWARD -s 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT --wait]: exit status -1:
Failed to ensure iptables rules: Error checking rule existence: failed to check rule existence: running [/sbin/iptables -t nat -C POS TROUTING -s 10.244.0.0/16 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully --wait]: exit status -1:
```

Can someone explain what this kind of messages are indicating? Can this be a hardware problem? Does it make sense to switch form flannel to another kuberentes container network interface (CNI) - e.g. [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/about/about-calico)?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+iptables+segfault+ip+

Comment: Apols @Ralph I see you there on GH! :)

Comment: yes, but I am still not able to understand what the message tries to tell me? Is it just a bug in libnftnl.so ?

Comment: What os are running your nodes with? Did you disabled `firewalld`, selinux etc? How did you bootstrap your cluster?

Comment: I am running debian buster. I bootstrap the cluster with the official guide of kubeadm with containerd

Comment: Yes from a quick reading of the issues that you touched I got the sense that the problem was down around libnftnl ...

Comment: I am running through a kubeadm install myself today on Ubuntu 18.05.5 LTS, iptables v.1.6.1,  I'll use flannel and see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can see that debian buster uses nftables instead of iptables which is at this point incompatible with Kubernetes. Calico supports nft backed with `FELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND`. I would suggest swapping the CNI for calico.

Comment: thanks for your responses. I will give calico a try and I will post my results here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments debian buster uses nftables backed instead of iptables:

> **NOTE: iptables is being replaced by  [nftables](https://wiki.debian.org/nftables)  starting with Debian Buster** - reference [here](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables)

Unfortunately the nftables are [not compatible](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#ensure-iptables-tooling-does-not-use-the-nftables-backend) at this moment with kubernetes.

In Linux, nftables is available as a modern replacement for the kernel’s iptables subsystem. The  `iptables`  tooling can act as a compatibility layer, behaving like iptables but actually configuring nftables. This nftables backend is not compatible with the current kubeadm packages: it causes duplicated firewall rules and breaks  `kube-proxy`. You could try to switch to legacy option like described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1025176/debian-10-how-can-i-disable-nftables-and-continue-to-use-iptables-only) but I'm not sure about this solution as I don't have a way to test it with your Os. I solved similar case with debian with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978030/kubernetes-pods-not-accessible-within-the-cluster/62031947#62031947).

Alternative way would to switch to Calico which actually [supports nftbacked](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/felix/configuration) with `FELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND`. This parameter controls which variant of iptables binary Felix uses. Set this to  `Auto`  for auto detection of the backend. If a specific backend is needed then use  `NFT`  for hosts using a netfilter backend or  `Legacy`  for others. [Default:  `Auto`].

When installing calico with containerd please also have a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744000/kubernetes-1-17-containerd-1-2-0-with-calico-cni-node-not-joining-to-master) case.

Comment: I switched from flannel to [calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/) and now the messages are gone.